# What does the `execute <<-SQL` mean in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

When I'm referring to active_record_migrations online in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

In the following snippet:

> ```
> class ExampleMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
>   def up
>     create_table :distributors do |t|
>       t.string :zipcode
>     end
>
>     # add a CHECK constraint
>     execute <<-SQL
>       ALTER TABLE distributors
>         ADD CONSTRAINT zipchk
>         CHECK (char_length(zipcode) = 5);
>     SQL
>
>     add_column :users, :home_page_url, :string
>     rename_column :users, :email, :email_address
>   end
>
>   def down
>     rename_column :users, :email_address, :email
>     remove_column :users, :home_page_url
>
>     execute <<-SQL
>       ALTER TABLE distributors
>         DROP CONSTRAINT zipchk
>     SQL
>
>     drop_table :distributors
>   end
> end
> ```

what does the following statement mean?

```
execute <<-SQL
  ALTER TABLE distributors
    ADD CONSTRAINT zipchk
    CHECK (char_length(zipcode) = 5);
SQL
```

Running this migration with `rails db:migrate`, I get the error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "CONSTRAINT": syntax error:           ALTER TABLE distributors
            ADD CONSTRAINT zipchk
              CHECK (char_length(zipcode) = 5) NO INHERIT;
```

Refer to [3.9 Using reversible](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) for more details.

Answer (score 20):

It is called [heredoc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents) and has nothing to do with migrations, SQL or anything else specifically:

> If you are writing a large block of text you may use a “here document”
>   or “heredoc”:
>
> ```
> expected_result = <<HEREDOC
>
> This would contain specially formatted text.
>
> That might span many lines
> HEREDOC
> ```
>
> The heredoc starts on the line following << HEREDOC and ends with the
>   next line that starts with HEREDOC. The result includes the ending
>   newline.
>
> You may use any identifier with a heredoc, but all-uppercase
>   identifiers are typically used.
>
> You may indent the ending identifier if you place a “-” after <<:
>
> ```
>   expected_result = <<-INDENTED_HEREDOC
> This would contain specially formatted text.
>
> That might span many lines
>   INDENTED_HEREDOC
> ```
>
> Note that the while the closing identifier may be indented, the
>   content is always treated as if it is flush left. If you indent the
>   content those spaces will appear in the output.

Since [ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::DatabaseStatements#`execute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-execute) takes a string as an argument, you are passing this string, just well formatted.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is used to have migrations created in sql fashion rather than following rails active record way.

Benefit: It provides more control over the SQL operations, adding indexes, constraints etc.

Syntax:

`execute <<-EOSQL
    your_sql_here 
  EOSQL`

`class CreateEmployers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-EOSQL
    CREATE TABLE employers (
     id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     designation_id int(11) NOT NULL,
     salary int(11) DEFAULT NULL);
    EOSQL
  end
  def down
    execute <<-EOSQL
     DROP TABLE employers;
    EOSQL
  end
end`

Comment: I'm using sqlite as the database. Is my syntax about creating CHECK constraint wrong?

Comment: heredoc has nothing to do with special migrations syntax. It also does not provide any more control over SQL operations. heredoc is used to write a `large block of text you`. Period.

Comment: @Andrey Deineko How should I do to fix this error? Is the sql syntax wrong?